# Want to integrate my application with World Server

Tags: publishing, workflow, worldserver

**I want to integrate my application with worldserver for data translation between different languages. As we all know worldserver would give us context in whichever language we need**

Here is the example API I found to login to world Server

The base URL for the REST API is: http(s)://{your-server-name}:{port-number}/ws-api/v1
The endpoints are then added to to that base URL and one has to make sure that the http request has a Content-Type header set to "application/json".

For example, to login you have to make a POST request to {BASE_URL}/login, set Content-Type to application/json and in the body of the request send following json:

{
"username":"your-username",
"password":"your-password"
}

as a response you would get something similar to the following json:
{
"sessionId": "956580144",
"expirationTime": "",
"userDetails": {
"fullName": "Admin",
"fingerprint": "2b35927d-cfef-4884-80bd-9d73ca849965",
"language": {
"id": 1033,
"languageCode": "en",
"countryCode": "US",
"locale": "en_US_English (United States)"
},
"regionalSettingsLocale": "en_US_English (United States)"
},
"loginOutcome": "LOGIN_SUCCEEDED",
"lastUpdateTime": 1465461211916,
"daysToPwdExpire": -1
}

What's important is the session id since this is used as session token for all the subsequent requests.

I'm looking for more API's like , what exactly is there work flow. 
Once login, What is the API to send me text/description they would process that.

And what is there process of work ? In which API endpoint they are going to show us the status?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. I would recommend you reading this - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - about how to ask a question.

The community is quite helpful, but none of us here is actually working for you - please share details about what you have done, what effort you have done and then ask for specific detail - that way you will more helpful answers

Comment: @PankajGaur I have edited my question with more details

Comment: This stack exchange site is about SDL Web (aka Tridion), which is a Web Content Management and Delivery System. Your question is about SDL World Server, which is a Translation Management System. You may be better off asking your question at the API Q&A Forum for WorldServer here: https://community.sdl.com/developers/language-developers/f/283

Answer (score 2):

You can get the information of all the Rest API endpoints from the WS server url:

http://{your-server-name}:{port-number}/ws-api/docs/ws-api-doc-v1.html

Hope that helps